# Unable to connect with azure service bus topics

Tags: c#, azure, subscription, servicebus

I have create small Poc to send message to azure service bus topic.My code is running without any exception but message not seen in azure service bus topic.
if any body have any idea about that,please suggest solution.

class Program

```
{
    const string ServiceBusConnectionString
        = "Endpoint=sb://etservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ServiceBusTopicSubsription;SharedAccessKey=Q4Cc+xP07NN4R0w=";
    const string TopicName = "topic1";
    static ITopicClient topicClient;
    static void Main()
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            topicClient = new TopicClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName);

            // Send messages
            string message = "Testing Message";

            await topicClient.SendAsync(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }
}
```

I am attaching snap shot of my code and azure portal details.

[C# Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPWDg.jpg)
[Azure Portal SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojm3a.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question to include the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are not awaiting the async method call so any errors might be lost.

Comment: applied await and now getting below error.

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ErrorCode: ConnectionRefused

Comment: Can you please edit the question and 1) post the code there instead of using an image and 2) include the error message in the question as well. Easier to read for everybody.

Comment: And given the error message I suggest you check the connectionstring and possible firewall issues.

Comment: connection string is ok. there may be issue with firewell as i am working from corporate network.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it on my side with you mentioned code. If create a new topic or new servicebus account is possible, please use a new servicebus or new topic and try it again. The following is my test result on my side. We also could use [Azure service bus explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to check the result. You also could get more demo could code from  [Get started with Service Bus topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions).

**Note:**

- I refresh topic from the azure portal, then I can get the message info in the azure portal.
- I use the RootManageSharedAccessKey

[image]